# lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /opt/extensions/cloudwatch_lambda_agent)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to install the Lambda Insights agent as an extension in container image. This is the dockerfile I used.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6

RUN curl -O https://lambda-insights-extension.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/amazon_linux/lambda-insights-extension.rpm && \
    rpm -U lambda-insights-extension.rpm && \
    rm -f lambda-insights-extension.rpm

COPY lambda_function.py   ./
CMD ["lambda_function.lambda_handler"]
```

Logs output when I invoke the lambda function

```
time="2021-07-04T13:11:45.804" level=info msg="exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)"

time="2021-07-04T13:11:53.438" level=info msg="extensionsDisabledByLayer(/opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j) -> stat /opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j: no such file or directory"

time="2021-07-04T13:11:53.442" level=warning msg="First fatal error stored in appctx: Extension.Crash"

time="2021-07-04T13:11:53.443" level=warning msg="Process 14(cloudwatch_lambda_agent) exited: exit status 1"

time="2021-07-04T13:11:53.443" level=error msg="Init failed" InvokeID= error="exit status 1"

time="2021-07-04T13:11:53.443" level=warning msg="Failed to send default error response: ErrInvalidInvokeID"

time="2021-07-04T13:11:53.444" level=error msg="INIT DONE failed: Extension.Crash"

time="2021-07-04T13:11:53.444" level=warning msg="Reset initiated: ReserveFail"


START RequestId: 6ad24517-92f2-477a-afb6-8289f1020930 Version: $LATEST

/opt/extensions/cloudwatch_lambda_agent: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /opt/extensions/cloudwatch_lambda_agent)
```

This works when aws python 3.8 base image is used but I need to use python 3.6.

Comment: This happens because 3.6 is based on Amazon Linux but 3.8 uses Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: @jordanm Any solution to this other than switching to 3.8?